# Modern UI how to go to another page from another link

Tags: c#, wpf, modern-ui

I am currently using Modern UI from CodePlex. It is great and easy to use but there are some classes and events that I am not familiar with. Example: I have two GroupLinks named "Patients" and "Configurations". There are several pages in each of the GroupLinks. I tried to navigate from one page to another using a button click event. It worked. But when I tried navigating from Page1 of GroupLink2 to Page1 of GroupLink1, it still worked, but the problem was the active GroupLink remained in GroupLink2 instead of GroupLink1 just like the screenshots show below:

[image: Configuration GroupLink2, I will click the New Entry]

[image: The page navigated to PatientPage, but the GroupLink is still GroupLink2]

Btw, I used the code behind to navigate from Allergies(IrritantPage) to PatientsPage:

```
private void FilterControl_OnToPatientClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {            
        NavigationCommands.GoToPage.Execute("/MainContents/PatientGridPage.xaml", this);
    }
```

So how do I solve this?

here are my MainWindow, Patient's Tab Page and Configuration's List Page

MODERN WINDOW (Main Window)

```
<mui:ModernWindow x:Class="DentalProto.MainWindow"
                  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                  xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                  xmlns:mui="http://firstfloorsoftware.com/ModernUI"
                  Title="Dental" IsTitleVisible="True"
                  WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen"
                  Width="1200"
                  Height="720"                       
                  ContentSource="/Pages/MainTabPage.xaml"
                  Closing="MainWindow_OnClosing"
                  >

    <mui:ModernWindow.MenuLinkGroups>
        <mui:LinkGroup DisplayName="User Name">
            <mui:LinkGroup.Links>

                <mui:Link DisplayName="Patients" Source="/Pages/MainTabPage.xaml" />
                <mui:Link DisplayName="Configurations" Source="/Pages/ConfigurationsListNav.xaml" />

            </mui:LinkGroup.Links>
        </mui:LinkGroup>

        <mui:LinkGroup DisplayName="settings" GroupKey="settings">
            <mui:LinkGroup.Links>
                <mui:Link DisplayName="software" Source="/Pages/SettingsPage.xaml" />
            </mui:LinkGroup.Links>
        </mui:LinkGroup>
    </mui:ModernWindow.MenuLinkGroups>

    <mui:ModernWindow.TitleLinks>
        <mui:Link DisplayName="settings" Source="/Pages/SettingsPage.xaml" />
        <mui:Link DisplayName="help" Source="https://www.facebook.com/" />
    </mui:ModernWindow.TitleLinks>
</mui:ModernWindow>
```

MAINTAB PAGE (Patient Page)

```
<UserControl x:Class="DentalProto.Pages.MainTabPage"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:mui="http://firstfloorsoftware.com/ModernUI"

             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="1280">
    <Grid >
        <!-- TODO: set @SelectedSource -->
        <mui:ModernTab Layout="Tab">
            <mui:ModernTab.Links>
                <!-- TODO: set @Source -->

                <mui:Link DisplayName="Patient" Source="/MainContents/PatientGridPage.xaml" />
                <mui:Link DisplayName="Treatment Record" Source="/MainContents/TreatmentFillInPage.xaml"/>

            </mui:ModernTab.Links>
        </mui:ModernTab>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

CONFIGURATIONLISTNAV (Configurations' Page)

```
<UserControl x:Class="DentalProto.Pages.ConfigurationsListNav"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:mui="http://firstfloorsoftware.com/ModernUI"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
    <Grid Style="{StaticResource ContentRoot}">
        <!-- TODO: set @SelectedSource -->
        <mui:ModernTab Layout="List">
            <mui:ModernTab.Links>
                <!-- TODO: set @Source -->
                <mui:Link DisplayName="Allergies" Source="/MainContents/IrritantGridPage.xaml"/>
                <mui:Link DisplayName="Health Diseases" Source="/MainContents/HealthDiseaseGridPage.xaml"/>
                <mui:Link DisplayName="Mouth Diseases" Source="/MainContents/MouthDiseaseGridPage.xaml"/>
                <mui:Link DisplayName="Procedures"  Source="/MainContents/ProcedureGridPage.xaml"/>
                <mui:Link DisplayName="Dentists" Source="/MainContents/DentistGridPage.xaml"/>
            </mui:ModernTab.Links>
        </mui:ModernTab>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are mixing "page" navigation with "tab" navigation inside the ModernTab control.

If you call `NavigationCommands.GoToPage.Execute` inside a ModernTab control you are changing the current "tab", not the current "page".

To change the top level page you can use:

```
IInputElement target = NavigationHelper.FindFrame("_top", this);
NavigationCommands.GoToPage.Execute("/Pages/BasicPage1.xaml", target);
```

If the new page is another ModernTab and you want to select a different tab then the default one, then you have to put in place some extra code.
In example you could pass parameters to the new page.
Se this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20316996/modern-ui-for-wpf-navigation) answer.

Comment: It worked!! I don't fully understand it, and I don't know _top means but it works, that's all it matters

Comment: I do something similar, but `target` is always null, regardless of `_top`, `_self`, `_parent`, etc. Any ideas?

Comment: @Mark Richman Be sure you're not doing it in IContent methods (OnFragmentNavigation etc) - it'll be null there always

Comment: @erem Yup. But if I do `NavigationCommands.GoToPage.Execute("Foo.xml", this)` from content pages without looking for a frame it does work.

Answer (score 2):

For anyone that may be struggling with this, set this in your MainWindow.cs constructor:

```
        Application.Current.MainWindow = this;
```

Then in the part of your application where you want to navigate to a page, run this:

```
        IInputElement target = NavigationHelper.FindFrame("_top", Application.Current.MainWindow);
        NavigationCommands.GoToPage.Execute("/NameOfYourPage.xaml", target);
```